# .htaccess rewrite rule does not match first occurrence

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

URL Format:

```
www.example.com/categ-id-title.html
www.example.com/news-1234-something-happened-in-2015-and-blabla.html
```

I tried to use a rewriteRule in .htaccess file, but it matches the second occurrence (**-2015-**) and not the first, the one I need (**-1234-**).

```
rewriteRule ^(.*)-([0-9]+)-(.*).html index.php?page=news&categ=$1&id=$2&title=$3 [L]
```

How could I force Apache to get the first occurence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `.*` is oto greedy, you can use this regex:

```
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([0-9]+)-(.*)\.html$ index.php?page=news&categ=$1&id=$2&title=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
rewriteRule ^(.*?)-([0-9]+)-(.*)\.html index.php?page=news&categ=$1&id=$2&title=$3 [L]
```